# TFS 2012 - Build Service Account always loses password

Tags: tfs

I have a build service setup within TFS and I have a special AD user set as the user to run the service. When I enter the credentials for that user within the TFS Admin Console, everything works fine. For some reason, after so long (not sure how long yet) the Build Service stops running. When I look into the issue, it is because the password is blank. Any ideas why this would be getting cleared out? If I put the password back in, everything will work fine until is clears out again.

Comment: Is the account a member of the local administrators group? There could be a group policy within AD that removes Log on as Service rights from such accounts on restart. See [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/20f1e103-6f3c-4b76-b1fd-de4f2fe90983/log-on-as-service-right-getting-removed-from-account-after-windows-server-2008-is-restarted?forum=winservergen) for an example

Comment: I'll ask our AD guy and see if he can spot anything. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: So that was it. Thanks! I'd love to give you credit for the answer......

Comment: No problem, I'll add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the account a member of the local administrators group? There could be a group policy within AD that removes Log on as Service rights from such accounts on restart. See [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/20f1e103-6f3c-4b76-b1fd-de4f2fe90983/log-on-as-service-right-getting-removed-from-account-after-windows-server-2008-is-restarted?forum=winservergen) for an example